# Threading With List Property

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety, task

```
public static class People
{
      List<string> names {get; set;}
}

public class Threading
{
     public static async Task DoSomething()
     { 
         var t1 = new Task1("bob");
         var t2 = new Task1("erin"); 
         await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2);  
     }
     private static async Task Task1(string name)
     {
         await Task.Run(() =>
         {
            if(People.names == null) People.names = new List<string>();
            Peoples.names.Add(name);
         }
     }
}
```

Is that dangerous to initialize a list within a thread? Is it possible that both threads could initialize the list and remove one of the names?

So I was thinking of three options:

1. Leave it like this since it is simple - only if it is safe though
2. Do same code but use a concurrentBag - I know thread safe but is initialize safe
3. Using [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = new List())] and then just do .Add in Task1 and not worry about initializing. But the only con to this is sometimes the list wont need to be used at all and it seems like a waste to initialize it everytime.

Comment: synchronisation. you have none.

Comment: Why do you even try to new it up in the threads - why not just `public static List<string> names = new List<string>();` (btw: the `static` is missing in your code)

Comment: Use `Lazy`. And learn something about multi-threading before writing multi-threaded code.

Comment: and **YES** - this is *NOT* threadsafe (`List<T>` itself is not threadsafe - you are in deep S*** if you change the collection while another thread is reading it) - that is why there are the collections in `System.Collections.Concurrent`

Comment: @CarstenKönig you should throw your comments in an answer with a simple rewrite how you would change the Task1 method, I think your observation is the correct one.

Comment: My bad I had a lot more code than this. I just tried to simplify to make easier to read and narrow in on my question. Basically I have a task which is being called more than once which is adding objects to a list property. And I was wondering if safe to initialize it in the task if it has not been so yet.

Comment: no it is not - an neither is adding items

Comment: Your `async` method isn't actually asynchronous.  You should be getting a warning since you aren't `await`ing anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for a simple case like this the easiest way to get thread-safety is using the `lock` statement:

```
public static class People
{
  static List<string> _names = new List<string>();

  public static void AddName(string name)
  {
     lock (_names)
     {
        _names.Add(name);
     }
  }

  public static IEnumerable<string> GetNames()
  {
     lock(_names)
     {
        return _names.ToArray();
     }
  }
}

public class Threading
{
     public static async Task DoSomething()
     { 
         var t1 = new Task1("bob");
         var t2 = new Task1("erin"); 
         await Task.WhenAll(t1,t2);  
     }
     private static async Task Task1(string name)
     {
         People.AddName(name);
     }
}
```

of course it's not very usefull (why not just add without the threads) - but I hope you get the idea.

If you don't use some kind of lock and concurrently read and write to a `List` you will most likely get an `InvalidOperationException` saying the collection has changed during read.

Because you don't really know when a user will use the collection you might return the easiest way to get thread-saftey is copying the collection into an array and returning this.

If this is not practical (collection to large, ..) you have to use the classes in [System.Collections.Concurrrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.concurrent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example the [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but those are a bit more involved.

Comment: Don't lock on public properties, fields or variables. Use a private object and lock on that (eg. `private readonly object _padlock = new object(); /* ... */ lock (_padlock) { /* ... */ }`).

Comment: Also, if you're mutating a list from multiple threads you *might* get an concurrent modification exception, but what's so dangerous is that all sorts of really bad things can happen *besides* throwing an exception.  You could just get the wrong value when you try to read something, you could corrupt the list's backing store and get back an item that never existed, you could bring down the whole runtime as a result of that (not through an exception, but through an invalid program state that even the .NET runtime didn't expect), an operation you perform could be ignored, etc.

Comment: @Servy, oh, I thought it was public. With a lock everything you say won't happen; that's the point of the lock.

Comment: @CMircea My previous comment was referring to your second to last paragraph, in which you incorrectly state the consequences of not synchronizing access to an object used by multiple threads.

Comment: @Servy sorry but most of what your write there is just wrong for the .net framework - I advise you to try a bit for yourself - if you manage to "bring down the whole runtime" sent me a message with the link to the code

Comment: @CarstenKönig In retrospect that case might not be possible.  Every single other one is though, so saying that they're mostly wrong is just not the case.  If you think that the only possible result of unsafe multithreaded access to a `List` is an InvalidOperationException is very, very wrong.

Comment: where did I say that this is the only possible result? I included this because I was asked in the comments above - the InvalidOperationException is the most visible problem you will acutally see if you happen to change the collection while iterating over it (the same as when you delete/add items IN the iteration) - maybe the wording was a bit off and I gonna change it slightly

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I figured worked best for my case was I used a lock statement.

```
public class Class1
{ 

  private static Object thisLock = new Object();

  private static async Task Task1(string name)
  {
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
          AddToList(name);
      }
  }

  private static AddToList(string name)
  {
      lock(thisLock)
      {
          if(People.names == null) People.names = new List<string>();
          People.names.Add(name);
      }
  }
}

public static class People
{
    public static List<string> names {get; set;}
}
```